# Sending email from Google, Amazon and own mailserver from same domain with DKIM

Tags: email, dkim, amazon-ses

I have a domain (example.org) for a organization, and we send different types of e-mail:

- I send email (From: user1@example.org), using my local email-server
- An other user (From: user2@example.org) are sending email via Gmail
- Our monthly newsletter and transactional emails (From:
  post@example.org) are sent via Amazon SES.

We have SPF record for all domain (_spf.google.com, amazonses.com and my own mail-server).

My questions:

- Can I implement DKIM without too much trouble?
- Can I use the same key, or do I need three different keys?
- Can I turn on DKIM for Amazon, and that will not effect e-mail sent
  from Google or my own server?

Answer (score 0):

If you turn on DKIM with AES and you have DKIM on your local and lets say your local server stamps a DKIM then Amazon will stamp a DKIM and you will have 2 DKIM signatures on your emails. (Which I seen a lot)

Amazon will have their own DKIM Key, and you will have your own DKIM, and Gmail will have their own DKIM.

A lot of people do what you're trying to do, if configured right and you're not relaying through amazon on gmail then you'll end up with one DKIM Signature (which is ideally what you want)

Relaying will cause the DKIM to fall out of Alignment and might cause some issues with DMARC.

But ultimately just test it, this [Mail Tester](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/resources/emailauthentication/), will pick up on multiple DKIM signatures. But I don't think it will be an issue.